# Limiting a foreach loop to the first array

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach, limit

here is my code:

```
<?php
         foreach ($productsRecord['images'] as $upload):?>
          <?php if ($upload['hasThumbnail']): ?>
            <a href="<?php echo $upload['urlPath'] ?>" rel="lightbox" class="imgborder" title="<?php echo $productsRecord['name'] ?>"><img src="<?php echo $upload['urlPath'] ?>"  alt="" /></a><br />



          <?php endif ?>
        <?php endforeach ?>
```

How would I go about limiting the results to only the first result, would I use a break; statement?

Cheers

Comment: Can you elaborate it a bit more? Do you want just the first element of `$productsRecord['images']` ?

Comment: Yes, I just want the first image to appear.

Comment: then just use the first element of the array directly.. Why do you even need to loop for just one element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use current()

your code shall like that:

```
<?php reset($productsRecord['images']); ?>
<?php $upload = current($productsRecord['images']);?>
<?php if ($upload['hasThumbnail']): ?>
    <a href="<?php echo $upload['urlPath'] ?>" rel="lightbox" class="imgborder" title="<?php echo $productsRecord['name'] ?>"><img src="<?php echo $upload['urlPath'] ?>"  alt="" /></a><br />
<?php endif ?>
```

To more information about the current() check the manual:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.current.php

Comment: Or if you want to be absolutely sure that you get the first element, use [`reset`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.reset.php) instead of `current`

Comment: @user1463691 if worked as needed plz mark the answer as correct :)

Answer (score 2):

Just use the first element of the array directly

```
$productsRecord['images'][0]
```

No need to loop here.

Comment: Just as a hint: On SO, you will want to indent code with four spaces so it is properly highlighted. If you want to include a variable or function name (or something else) within regular text, you can use inline highlighting by surrounding the code with backticks (`).

Comment: Also, as a good practice, you should always check if an index in an array exists before retrieving it. That way you avoid nasty undefined index warnings.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use break

```
    <?php break; endforeach; ?>
```